# Does Google Maps Api Elevation Service provide the Height of a position (or altitude)?

Tags: google-maps, elevation

I have a general question about the Google Maps API Elevation Service. 
Does the Elevation service provides only the Ground height from geoid (from sea level) for a specific position?

Or does it returns the height (or altitude) of a specific position?
I am new about Google Maps Api Elevation service.
I like to get the height of an object while moving (for example a bike). The bike can jump from the ground. So I want to catch the height of the bike as well, so that I can calculate the height curve of that bike.

Is this that Google Maps Api Elevation service can support?
Or does it something else (calculate height from gyroscope, accelerometer etc.)
I will be grateful if someone can provide some guide line about that.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/elevation/) provided by Google:

> The Elevation service provides elevation data for locations on the
>   surface of the earth, including depth locations on the ocean floor
>   (which return negative values). In those cases where Google does not
>   possess exact elevation measurements at the precise location you
>   request, the service will interpolate and return an averaged value
>   using the four nearest locations.

It will not provide information related to bike jumps. It's not that exact. For that type of information you'd need to take the data directly from hardware on the bicycle.